# jQuery in Windows 8 JS Applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows

Can we use frameworks like jQuery and jQuery UI in Windows 8 JS Applications? I can't find a document where I can read something about other frameworks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. The only thing needed is to add the required JavaScript files in your application in Visual Studio and include them from there. Using any CDN won't work as you can't load external JavaScript files in a Metro JavaScript application.

Comment: There are a few caveats here... ex. none of the jQuery AJAX calls will work since you need to use WinJS.xhr instead, though it wouldn't surprise me if wrappers/plugins emerge to resolve that transparently.

Comment: Ajax calls should work. However JSONP is not supported because script element injection is consider a security breach by WinJS

Answer (score 1):

There is some fix in jQuery library that you can include it in your Windows 8 development. 
Here is the link to get the jQuery library (with some fix to tailor for Wins 8).
https://github.com/appendto/jquery-win8 
The work is done by AppendTo and they had a joint talk with Microsoft at BUILD conference this year.
More detail for this jQuery library:
jQuery for Windows 8
With the recent release of Windows 8 many developers have eagerly set out to create jQuery-enhanced applications for Windows 8. Unfortunately, all of these individuals quickly learned that jQuery and Windows 8 initially suffer a bit of friction when brought together.
Faced with this issue, appendTo is pleased to release a custom copy of jQuery that will play nicely in Windows 8. Just download it, include it in your project, and you'll be up and running.
To ensure the project's direction was carefully planned, appendTo communicated with the jQuery team routinely to address any concerns about modifying some aspects of jQuery (or its Unit Tests) to improve compatability with Windows 8.
Given that this is a preview and you may come across issues in your own projects, we would like to encourage you to freely submit issues and feedback here on GitHub. We will do our best to answer your concerns in a timely manner, and resolve issues as quickly as possible.
Please note that in order to get the best experience with jQuery and Windows 8 you'll need more than a modified library, you will also need an understanding of basic security concerns in the Windows 8 environment. Many of these concerns are with how you, the developer, use $.html() (and other similar methods). Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh465388.aspx for further details.
Watch the presentation given at Build 2012 online at http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-130